# Como mudar tamanho do Popover no Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, popover

Tenho o seguinte código de um efeito popover com o Bootstrap 3, estou utilizando o Bootstrap 3.3.7. Esse *popover* funciona da seguinte maneira, quanto o mouse passa em cima desse ícone aparece a mensagem. Tenho vários *popovers* na página, mas esse em específico é muito grande o conteúdo e eu preciso aumentar o *width* dele para que não saia da área de visão. Alguém sabe como?

Segue como tá o meu código e imagem do *popover* em funcionamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="hover" title="<strong>Informação</strong>" data-content="conteudo vem aqui"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
```

-

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true});
```

Bibliotecas que estou utilizando além do arquivo Bootstrap.min.css baixado no site, a versão é a 3.3.7:

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cara vc está usando alguma outra biblioteca que tenha esse popover? Pois ele não parece ser o modelo default do Boostrap... Coloquei esse seu código ai usando os arquivos padrão da documentação eu não consegui simular esse comportamento. Inclua as demais informações na pergunta. Arquivos CSS e JS extras que tenha usado e tudo mais

Comment: @hugocsl atualizei a pergunta com todas as bibliotecas que estou utilizando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class `.popover` do Bootstrap 3 tem um `max-width` default de `270px`, basta vc substituir esse valor no `.popover` que venha seguido do `buttom` que tenha um `id` por exemplo...

```
#teste + .popover {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

Eu fiz assim, repare que um `.popover` tem uma largura default de 270px, e o `.popover` que vir depois do `buttom` com `id="teste"` vai ter a largura que coloquei no CSS de `350px`

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true});
```

```css
#teste + .popover {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<button type="button" id="teste" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">345</button>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">123</button>
```

Veja pelo *DevTools* que quando vc clica no `buttom` é adicionada em seguida dele uma `div` com a classe `.popover` conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Aqui está a documentação oficial do **Bootstrap 3** sobre o `Popover`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#live-demo-1

Comment: Sua resposta resolveu meu problema, obrigada!

Comment: @C.Oli legal que deu certo! Boa sorte ai com o projeto!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode aumentar não só o **width** do popover como qualquer outra propriedade Css dele normalmente:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true})
})
```

```css
.popover-content {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 300px;             // aumenta o width
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-teste="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" title="<strong>Informação</strong>" data-content="conteudo vem aqui"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
```

Comment: Teu método tbm me mostrou que da pra alterar não só o width, muito bom!